# Converting post response from json nested dict to python dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I've searched and tried. 
I'm getting response back to get my access token. Im trying to get the keys from the response but it's not working. Here's what I've tried:

```
r=requests.post(url, data=req_params) 
data=r.json()
```

data type = dict; data prints:

```
{u'access_token':lrga242jt204j, u'user':{u'username':u'someoneismad',u'bio':u'im mad'}}
```

When I access it:
`unicode has no attribute get`

Things I've tried

```
ast.literal_eval(data) #error malformed string
ast.literal_eval(str(data)) #malformed string
json.loads(r) #expected string or buffer
json.loads(str(r)) #no json could be decoded
```

[[update]]
accessing dict

```
data.get('access_token')
data['access_token']
data.get('access_token', {}).get('user_id')
```

Problem is that I run into unicode error as indicated above

Comment: How exactly are you trying to access the dict?

Comment: @jwodder I've updatd the problem. I've tried several ways but it gets me unicode error

Comment: what does repr(data) show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
r=requests.post(url, data=req_params) 
data=r.json()
access_token = data['access_token']
user_data = data['user']
username = user_data['username']
#or
username = data['user']['username']
```

It should print your access token.

Comment: yes it does, i've already tried but see above for the unicode error.

Comment: I added some more examples how to access the data in the dict.

Comment: sorry you are right... i've been accessing the wrong key! omg